# retrieving lines with patterns from multiple files

Tags: bash

I'm working on a project to download files from a server through an ftp connection, then scanning all those files for specific patterns in their lines, putting it into a file and uploading it to the same server i downloaded the first files.
Now im pretty sure than i need to make another script and use a for function to run the following script for all the files, the problem is don't really know how to correctly use for loops.
Basically I want to make the grep´s in the script to run for every file.
PS:sorry if I'm not being clear,thanks.

```
#!/bin/bash
if( grep -i z /home/user/file >> /dev/null )
     then
     echo" "
     grep-i "z" /home/user/file | head -1 >> holder
     echo " "
     grep -i "x" /home/user/file | head -1 >> holder
     echo " "
     grep -i "y" /home/user/file | head -1 >> holder
```

Comment: There are no loop in your code. You don't use any `ftp` in your code. Just `for file in /home/user/*; do grep ... "$file" | head -n1 .... ; done`. You can find much help [online](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-loop-over-file/) just search the topic..

Comment: i havent started doing that part yet, this is only the scanning the files part, by the way thanks for the link , its just what i wanted